# Use COUNTIFS with two criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am stuck please help me,
basically I want use a formula which counts data within the day range that ı have defined and also counts just the name I describe.
Likes data which is in photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu8Wi.png)

I want to learn just Anthony's done works number but just in first month like in 1/1/2019-1/30/2019

Sample Data

```
NAME       DATE        IS THERE ANY DONE WORK IN THIS DATE
anthony    1/1/2019    YES
jacob      1/25/2019   YES
anthony    1/30/2019   YES
justin     2/1/2019    YES
marc       2/5/2019    YES
anthony    3/1/2019    YES
jacob      3/1/2019    YES
```

Comment: So countifs() will work with 2 or more criteria. Show you have implemented it so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can insert a column nest to your data, then enter a formula nest to each record as shown in the formula bar in the following screenshot and then use the sumifs formula to sum the total work done or countifs to count the number or records, Else, if its a huge data you can also create a pivot table as shown

[image]

Now that you have edited your question, I have to edit my anser:)

See SUMIFS formula in the image above.
Just replace if with COUNTIFS and add once more argument for work (F) column to check if it is = YES

so your new formula will be
COUNTIFS(D7:D13,"a",G7:G13,1,F7:F13,"YES")

This link will help you.. Please check

https://exceljet.net/formula/new-customers-per-month

Comment: can you check my last answer please.

Comment: but is this formula checks both date and name ? beacuse ı want if name is anthony and if it is in first month then it should count YES datas or name is anthony but if it is just in second month

Comment: If you want the result to be 2 For Antony For Jan For YES, then the countifs formula in the edited answer is working correctly. You will have to check Name, Month and YES columns

Comment: ı want to use your formula in 7000 lines excel because of that it is impossible to write month's number to next. Can we make check date datas from directly E column ?

Comment: This link will help you .. Please see https://exceljet.net/formula/new-customers-per-month

Comment: If this answered your question please upvote/mark it as solved .. See the link : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score -1):

ı changed the data image.Can you look again ? ı want count the data whıch i said and see in other sheet page like images and also want when ı change name from list it should changed datas.    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRWtW.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRWtW.png    [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJAAN.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJAAN.png    [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKT97.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKT97.png

Comment: When it says "enter image description here", you're actually supposed to do that...

Comment: Also please don't write answers that aren't answers

Comment: sorry ı am new in stack ı am trying to learn ı changed the images thank you for replying.Can you see images now ?